# How to call a function within another function in Shell Script?

Tags: bash

Say I have this function:

```
function run_sanity_check(){
   echo -e "This is test level 1\n"
   echo -e "This is test level 2\n"
}
```

and this other function:

```
function run_test(){
  ... environment setup routine runs here
  echo -e "Running tests...\n"

  run_sanity_check --> this would be my call for the function above
}
```

When I call "run_test" I get this error: 
function: not found

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you want either the parens or the `function` keyword but not both.  Your problem is not with the invocation it's with the definition.  See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Brian's comment mentions, you need to use either `function` or `()` but not both.

Both of the following are valid, based on [the documentation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html).

```
function run_sanity_check{
   echo -e "This is test level 1\n"
   echo -e "This is test level 2\n"
}


run_sanity_check(){
   echo -e "This is test level 1\n"
   echo -e "This is test level 2\n"
}
```

The following script prints expected output.

```
run_sanity_check(){
   echo -e "This is test level 1\n"
   echo -e "This is test level 2\n"
}

run_test(){
  echo -e "Running tests...\n"

  run_sanity_check 
}

run_test
```

Comment: I removed the "function" keyword and now it completely ignores the inner function call.

Comment: @leofelipe, Did you remove it from both?

Comment: @ merlin2011, Yes, I did.

Comment: @leofelipe, I just posted a fully working script. It may be that something else is breaking with your script that you're not showing.

Comment: Yup, I tested here too and your script works just fine. Let me look further into the script and try to figure out what is going on. Thank you.